# Converting a string, containing a number with scientific notation, to number

Tags: javascript, string, api, integer, metabase

I'm asking this to see if there is an easier way to do this.. I have an `API` that gives me `8.419379055475514E7` as an answer, but I need the number with no scientific notation, so instead of looking for the `E` in the string to detect the last number I want to know if there is something that already does this, I'm doing it on JS and the API is from `Metabase`.
Thanks!

Looking for the last number before the `E`, then multiply it by the number that is after the `E`. Works

Comment: Most ways of creating a number support exponential notation. eg, `Number("8.419379055475514E7")` or `+"8.419379055475514E7"` or `parseFloat("8.419379055475514E7")`

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and it works :)